# What gives Steam XP?

Tags: steam, achievements, steam-trading-cards

From the [faq](http://steamcommunity.com/tradingcards/faq) I know that the following give XP:

- Crafting a badge ("most badges give 100 XP")
- Upgrading a badge (it looks the same as crafting a badge: mostly 100 XP)
- Years of Service badge (the faq is vague. What is the formula for XP gained?)
- "Special events on Steam also frequently have badges" (?)

What other activities give XP? Are there any ways to get XP other than getting badges? Do regular achievements for Steam games give XP?

Comment: Great question :) !

Answer (score 35, accepted):

From what I've seen so far:

- Crafting a game badge grants 100 XP
- Leveling a game badge grants 100 XP
- Years of Service awards 50 XP per year
- The games in your game collection award XP (The math is not clear to me, [I have](http://steamcommunity.com/id/agent86/badges/13) 414 for 209 games currently)

Steam Special Events appear to grant XP, although the formula is unclear to me.  The individual data is incomplete for most of the previous events.  Ones that I can confirm count for some amount of XP are:

- Steam Holiday Sale (2011 & 2012) - I've seen up to 130 XP for 2011, and 100 for 2012
- Steam Summer Sale (2012) - I have this one complete, I believe, for 100 XP
- Steam Summer Camp (2011) - I've seen up to 130 XP
- The Potato Sack (2011) - a "gold potato" gives 200 XP
- The Great Steam Treasure Hunt (2010) - I've seen this one up to 130 XP

For community contributions there are other bonuses (with thanks to Koraktor in the comments):

- Anyone can get the Pillar of Community (100 XP) or Community Ambassador (100 XP) badges for doing some simple tasks related to their Steam profile.
- Some [translators](http://translation.steampowered.com/) get a badge worth 100 XP
- [Steamworks developers](https://partner.steamgames.com/) get a badge worth 500 XP
- [Community moderators](http://steamcommunity.com/id/Sierra_Oscar/badges/10) get a badge worth 500 XP
- Valve employees also get a [1000 XP bonus](http://steamcommunity.com/id/them/badges/11), although that one might be kind of hard to get ;)

Comment: There are also additional badges for translators (100 XP), Steamworks developers (500 XP) and community moderators (500 XP)

Comment: And great answer ;)

Comment: Might be worth mentioning, Community Ambassador is the level 2 version of Pillar of Community. It's gained after 22/26 community tasks are completed.

Comment: They added today another one, Game Collector. It gives XP depending on number of games in user's library. It seems to be linear, with 203 games it gave me 402 XP and with 207 games it was 405 XP. For more details and source [see](http://steamcommunity.com/groups/tradingcards#announcements/detail/1837748658627226301).

Comment: @slawek, thanks for the heads up, I added that info to the answer

Comment: @agent86 The values for the game collection badge XP changed July 24, 2013. The formula has always been linear only within each tier. Here's what they now work out to based on sample data: 1-> 94+6*#ofGames XP, 5-> 100+5*#ofGames XP, 10-> floor(116.5+3.35*#ofGames) XP, 25 -> 150+2*#ofGames XP
50 -> floor(175+1.5*#ofGames) XP, 100 -> floor(208.25+1.1675*#ofGames) XP (approx. Still testing)
all tiers above 250 -> 250+#ofGames XP. Each tier gets a base value and each game past the tier threshold gets a multiplier and is added - I just worked back from the threshold to make simpler math.

Comment: Also, Community Ambassador is 200 XP, not 100.

Comment: for games you own: +100 first games, then + how much money you spend.

Comment: The translator badge is AFAIK awarded by being a top 10 translator for 12 weeks straight.